# Disable password limitations

Tags: user-registration, password

I had a "learnpress" plugin in my Wordpress website that uses default registration wordpress setting, but I'd like to remove all limitations of password including length (12 character), adding number and I'd like to be able to set a password in other languages too.

I tried this code in Functions.php but it didn't work! any ideas?

```
function wc_remove_password_strength() {
if ( wp_script_is( 'wc-password-strength-meter', 'enqueued' ) ) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );
       }
  }

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wc_remove_password_strength', 100 );
```

Comment: you use woocommerce?

Comment: @vikrantzilpe, No sir I use directly the bank gate. Not woocommerce

Answer (score 1):

**if you use wocommerce please try this code to your current theme functions.php**

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_deactivate_pass_strength_meter', 10 );

function misha_deactivate_pass_strength_meter() {

wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );

}

Comment: No sir I don't have  woocommerce. I use the bank port directly.